# Drawing 200 textures in LibGdx based Android game

Tags: android, libgdx

When I draw more around 100-200 textures all in the same screen, the device becomes very slow and the app crashes without any exceptions. Could you please let me know any best way to have 100 textures without compromising the performance.

- I am using the TextureRegion from TextureAtlas.

### MainGame

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("BallPoolGame Screen - render"); 
    batch = sb;

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(BACKGROUND_BALL_POOL, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT); 
    cellManager.draw(sb); 
    ballManager.draw(sb); 

    sb.end();
}


private void setGameTextures() {
    gameScreenAtlas = new TextureAtlas("data/texturetutorialpack.pack"); 

    RED_BALL  = gameScreenAtlas.findRegion("redball"); 
//  RED_BALL.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    BLUE_BALL = gameScreenAtlas.findRegion("blueball"); 
//  BLUE_BALL.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    GREEN_BALL = gameScreenAtlas.findRegion("greenball"); 
//  GREEN_BALL.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
}
```

### CellManager

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch sb){   
    batch=sb; 
    showImageTexture(MODEL1,207,1);  
    if(showSelectedCell){      
        if(allPossiblePathSize>0)
            setupBoardCellTexture();  
        showImage(CELL_SELECTED, rowCoordinate[cellRow], colCoordinate[cellCol]); 
    } 
}

private void setupBoardCellTexture(){ 
    for(CellGrid c : masterGrid){  
        if(cellTextureIndicator[c.getRow()][c.getCol()]==1){
            showImage(CELL_ALL_PATH_TEXTURE,c.getRowCoordinate() ,c.getColCoordinate() );    
        } 
    }

}

private void showImage(TextureRegion tr, float rowCoordinate, float colCoordinate) {
    batch.draw(tr, colCoordinate,rowCoordinate);
}
```

**BallManager**

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch sb) {
    batch = sb;
    setupBoardBallTexture();
    if (moveTheBall) {
        updateBallPosition();
        showImage(ball.getTextureRegion(), moveRow + 6, moveCol + 6);
    }
    squeezeBalls.draw(sb);

}
```

Comment: How are you loading the textures (please provide code)? What device or emulator are they crashing on? You say there aren't exceptions, but might there be anything else in the logcat related to the process ending?

Comment: Show us your render() method.

Comment: I don't see anything bad here, but it's still missing the standard render() method.

Comment: Whats is standard render() method

Comment: The one without parameters, or the deltatime. From either `ApplicationListener`, or `Screen`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some essential data about your app to answer than question:

1. How big is one texture on average (Size: widthxheight)
2. On which device is this error occuring (some devices might have less fillrate than others)
3. What texture filter does the TextureAtlas use (LINEAR, NEAREST, ...)

I guess that you are trying to draw many textures event if they are out of sight. If that is the case you have to implement a check if the cell is visible to the camera.

Another guess would be that you are trying to draw too many elements with the LINEAR TextureFilter. When using linear as a texture filter the gpu needs to sample way more points then with nearest (i think it was 4 times the samples; so in theory your gpu draws 400-800 textures; depending on images size that are too much for mobile gpu fillrates)

Try to describe more circumstances then i can give probably more insight in your problem.

Comment: 1st case : In my case It was with the bigger size textures with Linear filter. I have reduced the number of textures by putting the static Textures in the background screen.   2nd Case : There were around 200 textures drawn with the Linear filter each of size 120x120. I drawn programmatically all these Textures to plan some special effect. I finally made them in the game screen background to avoid these many drawing in render(). Finally it is fine now